# Is it possible to write a simple user-space code to monitor a uevent?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, udev, netlink

I am working on a simple project that (as I would like it to be) monitors a uevent for just one possible device and then receives data from it. I am using this on eLinux ported on a BeagleBone Black. Now, I know udev does exactly that albeit for every possible device. I wanted to know if would be possible to write a userspace program that listens to just this uevent and takes appropriate action.

Comment: hi and welcome, can you provide your attempts so far so we can help. FYI the community is rarely inclined to code for you without evidence of effort.

Comment: Thank you. I am still researching on udev and have not begun coding as of yet. will be implementing interfacing of a device right from the time it is plugged to transfer of data between a userspace process and the said device through the kernel using netlink. That is when i stumbled on to udev which is a behemoth. So i wanted to know if it would be possible to implement a small daemon to monitor uevent just for one specific device. I am not looking for code but advice on how i can go about it. I am new to kernel and device drivers. Let me know if there's anything wrong with my approach.